# How can I parse recursive data structures with JSON.NET?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have `MENUITEM` and `SCREEN` entries defined in a root element `MENUSTRUCT` from a json string.

The important thing here is that a `MENUITEM` can contain other `MENUITEM`s or `SCREEN`s.

I want to parse the whole json string with JSON.NET where I should receive a tree with `MENUITEM`s that can contain a huge chain of nested `MENUITEM`s or `SCREEN` entries.

I snipped a lot of the nested structures from the following json string:

```
{
"MENUSTRUCT": {
"-text": "GUI.Menu.Root",
"-image": "GUI.Menu.Home",
"-mask": "GUI.Menu.Home.Mask",
"-color": "#E0E0FF",
"-menuid": "MENUTREE",
"MENUITEM": [
  {
    "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.00000003",
    "-image": "GUI.Menu.Menu",
    "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Menu.Mask",
    "-color": "#C0C0FF",
    "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00000003",
    "SCREEN": [
      {
        "-id": "GUI.Dlg.StartupScreen",
        "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.00000103",
        "-image": "GUI.Menu.Screen",
        "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Screen.Mask",
        "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00000103"
      },
      {
        "-id": "GUI.Dlg.Calls",
        "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.Calls",
        "-image": "GUI.Menu.Screen",
        "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Screen.Mask",
        "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00000203"
      }
    ],
    "MENUITEM": [
      {
        "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.00000603",
        "-image": "GUI.Menu.Menu",
        "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Menu.Mask",
        "-color": "#A0A0FF",
        "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00000603",
        "SCREEN": [
          {
            "-id": "GUI.Dlg.SpecialTrips",
            "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.00010603",
            "-image": "GUI.Menu.Screen",
            "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Screen.Mask",
            "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00010603"
          },
          {
            "-id": "GUI.Dlg.SpecialTrips",
            "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.00020603",
            "-image": "GUI.Menu.Screen",
            "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Screen.Mask",
            "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00020603"
          }
         ]  // end of screen
        }
     ]     // end of nested menuitem
  },
      /* snipped following menuitems */
]  // end of menuitem array
}
}
```

I tried to deserialize the whole thing with

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MenuItem>>(jsonString);
```

I have an object `MenuItem` which has a property of `List<Screen>` and one of `List<MenuItem>` but the whole thing doesn't work out. I think the deserializer is not able to handle the nested `MenuItem`s.

I also tried to parse the tree with `JObject` but I think this way you need to implement a lot of the parsing by yourself.

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);   
var menuItems = from m in obj["MENUSTRUCT"]["MENUITEM"].Children() select m;
List<MenuEntry> menues = this.LoadMenuStructure(menuItems);
```

Here I have to make sure that I am on the correct `JToken` but I have no idea if I'm handling with a `MenuItem` or a `Screen`.

Is there no other, easier, way to deserialize the the json string without nesting me through all the structures?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your Jason is not Valid I have updated your JSON script and validated it I will post the corrected script as well as a web site where you can run and validate your script

Comment: +1 for a well structured question by the way Saxos, try running this line again and use the debugger to check it and test the results before trying the other method of parsing `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MenuItem>>(jsonString);`

Comment: MENUSTRUCT, MENUITEM and SCREEN look very similar. Do they all contain the same fields ? In that case, DRY and consider merging them in a single class, and add a TYPE field.

Comment: Ah sorry for that. The json string should be OK. Maybe I just had a typo when I snipped the most of the entries for the SO question.
My general problem is that I do not fully understand the behaviour of JSON.NET. Is it possible at all to retrieve nested objects with `DeserializeObject`?

Comment: My json is valid. I tested id with JSONLint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original Script has errors in it and it has an additional blank `,` towards the bottom. I removed the C# `//` Comments tags as well this should work for you now

```
{
    "MENUSTRUCT": {
        "-text": "GUI.Menu.Root",
        "-image": "GUI.Menu.Home",
        "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Home.Mask",
        "-color": "#E0E0FF",
        "-menuid": "MENUTREE",
        "MENUITEM": [
            {
                "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.00000003",
                "-image": "GUI.Menu.Menu",
                "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Menu.Mask",
                "-color": "#C0C0FF",
                "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00000003",
                "SCREEN": [
                    {
                        "-id": "GUI.Dlg.StartupScreen",
                        "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.00000103",
                        "-image": "GUI.Menu.Screen",
                        "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Screen.Mask",
                        "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00000103"
                    },
                    {
                        "-id": "GUI.Dlg.Calls",
                        "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.Calls",
                        "-image": "GUI.Menu.Screen",
                        "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Screen.Mask",
                        "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00000203"
                    }
                ],
                "MENUITEM": [
                    {
                        "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.00000603",
                        "-image": "GUI.Menu.Menu",
                        "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Menu.Mask",
                        "-color": "#A0A0FF",
                        "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00000603",
                        "SCREEN": [
                            {
                                "-id": "GUI.Dlg.SpecialTrips",
                                "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.00010603",
                                "-image": "GUI.Menu.Screen",
                                "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Screen.Mask",
                                "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00010603"
                            },
                            {
                                "-id": "GUI.Dlg.SpecialTrips",
                                "-text": "GUI.Menu.Text.00020603",
                                "-image": "GUI.Menu.Screen",
                                "-mask": "GUI.Menu.Screen.Mask",
                                "-menuid": "Menu.ID.00020603"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

[JSONLint The JSON Validator](http://jsonlint.com/)